# while using proguard to shrink the apk size getting error as "java.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: xamarin.forms, apk, proguard, release

[My Android Options Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY7qP.png)

```
 My Proguard.cfg file:
    
    # This is Xamarin-specific (and enhanced) configuration.
    
    -dontobfuscate
    
    -keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
    -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
    
    -keep class mono.MonoRuntimeProvider { *; (...); }
    -keep class mono.MonoPackageManager { *; (...); }
    -keep class mono.MonoPackageManager_Resources { *; (...); }
    -keep class mono.android.** { *; (...); }
    -keep class mono.java.** { *; (...); }
    -keep class mono.javax.** { *; (...); }
    -keep class opentk.platform.android.AndroidGameView { *; (...); }
    -keep class opentk.GameViewBase { *; (...); }
    -keep class opentk_1_0.platform.android.AndroidGameView { *; (...); }
    -keep class opentk_1_0.GameViewBase { *; (...); }
    
    -keep class android.runtime.** { (***); }
    -keep class assembly_mono_android.android.runtime.** { (***); }
    # hash for android.runtime and assembly_mono_android.android.runtime.
    -keep class md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.** { *; (...); }
    -keepclassmembers class md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.** { *; (...); }
    
    # Android's template misses fluent setters...
    -keepclassmembers class * extends android.view.View {
       *** set*(***);
    }
    
    # also misses those inflated custom layout stuff from xml...
    -keepclassmembers class * extends android.view.View {
       (android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet);
       (android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int);
    }
    
    
Output window :
    
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$1: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$1: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$1: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$1: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$1: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$FileSaveTask: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$FileSaveTask: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$FileSaveTask: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$FileSaveTask: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$FileSaveTask: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$FileSaveTask: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$FileSaveTask: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$FileSaveTask: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserServiceFileProvider$FileSaveTask: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsService$1: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsService$1: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Resolver
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Resolver
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.FutureUtils: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.FutureUtils: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.FutureUtils: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.FutureUtils: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.FutureUtils: can't find referenced class androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.TokenContents: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.TokenContents: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.TrustedWebActivityServiceConnectionPool: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : androidx.browser.trusted.TrustedWebActivityServiceConnectionPool: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioRendererEventListener$EventDispatcher: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioRendererEventListener$EventDispatcher: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.FrameworkMediaDrm: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.FrameworkMediaDrm: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.amr.AmrExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.amr.AmrExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.flv.FlvExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.flv.FlvExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mkv.MatroskaExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mkv.MatroskaExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp3.Mp3Extractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp3.Mp3Extractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp4.FragmentedMp4Extractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp4.FragmentedMp4Extractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ogg.OggExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ogg.OggExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.Ac3Extractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.Ac3Extractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.AdtsExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.AdtsExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.PsExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.PsExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.TsExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.TsExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.wav.WavExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.wav.WavExtractor: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.metadata.id3.Id3Decoder: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.metadata.id3.Id3Decoder: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadHelper$1: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadHelper$1: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadManager: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadManager: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadManager$Task: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadManager$Task: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.CompositeMediaSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.CompositeMediaSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ConcatenatingMediaSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ConcatenatingMediaSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSourceEventListener$EventDispatcher: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSourceEventListener$EventDispatcher: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ads.AdsMediaSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ads.AdsMediaSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ads.AdsMediaSource$AdPrepareErrorListener: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ads.AdsMediaSource$AdPrepareErrorListener: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ads.AdsMediaSource$ComponentListener: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ads.AdsMediaSource$ComponentListener: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.DashMediaSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.DashMediaSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsSampleStreamWrapper: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsSampleStreamWrapper: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.DefaultHlsPlaylistTracker: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.DefaultHlsPlaylistTracker: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.smoothstreaming.SsMediaSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.smoothstreaming.SsMediaSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager$BitmapCallback: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager$BitmapCallback: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.TrackSelectionView: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.TrackSelectionView: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.spherical.SceneRenderer: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.spherical.SceneRenderer: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.spherical.SphericalSurfaceView: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.spherical.SphericalSurfaceView: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DummyDataSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DummyDataSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.CacheUtil: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.CacheUtil: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.EventDispatcher$HandlerAndListener: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.EventDispatcher$HandlerAndListener: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.SlidingPercentile: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.SlidingPercentile: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoRendererEventListener$EventDispatcher: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoRendererEventListener$EventDispatcher: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
    3>PROGUARD : warning : there were 142 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
```

Comment: Please help if somebody know what can I do?

Comment: If you set the linking to none,could it work ?